# Top 12 from union queries filtering max 12 rows Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am facing issue, that I need 12 max rows from 3 tables union data. But if any of the table do not have fixed rows than other table should be considered for remaining rows.

For example: I have 3 tables
Product
Category
Manufacturer

Case 1 : If all have 10 rows each than we should select 4 rows from each table.
Case 2: If product table have 3 rows and category an manufacturer have 5 rows 
each, than it should select 3 from product and 5 from category or manufacturer each.
Case 3: All have less than 4 rows than shows as many rows available.

Please help me to acheive this. I am posting my Stored Procedure which I have created till now.

```
  Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRowsfromtables]
    @SearchTerms nvarchar(150)
AS
BEGIN

create table #search (id int identity ,ids int, productname nvarchar(200),  categoryname nvarchar(200), tagname nvarchar(200), SeName nvarchar(200), displayorder int)
insert into #search
    Select Top 12 p.Id as ids, p.name as productname,  '' as categoryname, '' as tagname, '' as SeName, 0 as displayorder from Product p where p.Published = 1 and p.Deleted = 0 and name like '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'

    union

    Select Top 12 c.id as ids, '' as productname, c.name as categoryname, '' as tagname, '' as SeName , 1 as displayorder from Category c where c.Published = 1 and c.Deleted = 0 and Name like  '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'

    union

    Select Top 12 t.id as ids, '' as productname, '' as categoryname, t.Name as tagname, '' as SeName, 2 as displayorder
              from Manufacturer 
        where Name  like  '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'



    Select  id, ids,productname,categoryname, tagname, SeName, tagpcount,tagproductid,
     '' as ThumbnailImage, displayorder, (Select count(*) from #search where displayorder = 0) as ptotal, 
     (Select count(*) from #search where displayorder = 1) as ctotal,
     (Select count(*) from #search where displayorder = 2) as tagtotal,
      row_number() over(partition by displayorder order by id ) as rn
      from #search 

      order by displayorder

    drop table #search
END
```

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` gives you whatever the search engine picks.

Comment: Your are nearly there.  Your query selects from #search and applies an order (the column you alias rn) but then doesn't use it.  Order by rn and add TOP 12 to the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the windowed function [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to sequence the records within the union.  Then order the result by the row number:

```
/* Generate 13 sample records:
 *      Product         (4)
 *      Category        (6)
 *      Manufacturer    (3)
 */
WITH Product AS
    (
        -- Sample product records.
        SELECT
            Id
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1),
                    (2),
                    (3),
                    (4)
            ) AS x(Id)
    ),
    Category AS 
    (
        -- Sample category records.
        SELECT
            Id
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1),
                    (2),
                    (3),
                    (4),
                    (5),
                    (6)
            ) AS x(Id)
    ),
    Manufacturer AS
    (
        -- Sample manufacturer records.
        SELECT
            Id
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1),
                    (2),
                    (3)
            ) AS x(Id)
    )
SELECT TOP 12
    * 
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn,
                'P' AS Tbl,
                Id
            FROM
                Product

        UNION ALL

            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn,
                'C' AS Tbl,
                Id
            FROM
                Category

        UNION ALL

            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn,
                'M' AS Tbl,
                Id
            FROM
                Manufacturer
    ) AS u
ORDER BY
    rn
;
```

The order by will return all the records numbered 1 first, then 2 and so on.  This will provide as even a mix as the source data allows.

**EDIT**
Removed TOP from each of the subqueries.  I was trying to help SQL out by limiting the number of records it had to apply a row number to.  But the ROW_NUMBER is applied before the top, making this a somewhat pointless exercise.  My subqueries also lacked an ORDER BY clause.  Without this there is no guaranteed order, making "top" a pointless statement.

Comment: This I am doing already. I am using row_number to get numbering. But I am not able to fetch exact records.

This is my case:

Comment: I need that if 12 products are there and 10 categories are also there. Than it should pick 6 products and 6 categories. And if 12 products, 10 categories and 5 manufacturer, than it should pick 4 products, 4 categories and 4 manufacturer

Comment: This will do that.  What I've done here is combined three row numbers.  So each table will have a record 1, 2, 3, etc.  The top statement will return only the first 12, which could be made of 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 if only two of the tables have records.

Comment: I am not able to execute this query. Can you please help me in that. What these (1),
                    (2),
                    (3),
                    (4) 
Will have when writing the exact query?

Comment: That section is generating dummy data, so I could demonstrate the technique.  In your example you have a query `Select ... from #search order by displayorder`.  Changing this to `SELECT TOP 12 ... FROM #Search ORDER BY rn;` would return what you want.  You were on the right lines with the DisplayOrder column.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to run and get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to have an ORDER BY when using TOP or you will have no way of determining which top rows you will get. There also is not really a need to create a temp table here so you can select from it and then drop it. I added some (ok well a lot) of white space around your original so this is easier to see and maintain down the road. Something like this should be really close to what you after.

One thing important is you have a couple columns defined in your original query that were not in your defined temp table. No idea what you want to do with those so I just left them there.

```
Select top 12 id
    , ids
    , productname
    , categoryname
    , tagname
    , SeName
    , tagpcount
    , tagproductid
    , '' as ThumbnailImage
    , displayorder
    , ptotal = sum(case when displayorder = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    , ctotal = sum(case when displayorder = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    , tagtotal = sum(case when displayorder = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
    , row_number() over(partition by displayorder order by id ) as rn
from
(          
   Select Top 12 p.Id as ids
        , p.name as productname
        ,  '' as categoryname
        , '' as tagname
        , '' as SeName
        , 0 as displayorder 
    from Product p 
    where p.Published = 1 
        and p.Deleted = 0 
        and name like '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'
    ORDER BY p.name --or whatever column

    union ALL

    Select Top 12 c.id as ids
        , '' as productname
        , c.name as categoryname
        , '' as tagname
        , '' as SeName
        , 1 as displayorder 
    from Category c 
    where c.Published = 1 
        and c.Deleted = 0 
        and Name like  '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'
    ORDER BY c.name --or whatever column

    union ALL

    Select Top 12 t.id as ids
        , '' as productname
        , '' as categoryname
        , t.Name as tagname
        , '' as SeName
        , 2 as displayorder
    from Manufacturer 
    where Name  like  '%' + @SearchTerms + '%'
    ORDER BY t.Name --or whatever column
) x
group by id
    , ids
    , productname
    , categoryname
    , tagname
    , SeName
    , tagpcount
    , tagproductid
    , displayorder
order by displayorder
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. This query is getting only top 12 rows. So if there are 12 products than I got those only.

Comment: I need that if 12 products are there and 10 categories are also there. Than it should pick 6 products and 6 categories.

And if 12 products, 10 categories and 5 tags, than it should pick 4 products, 4 categories and 4 tags.

Comment: Then you need to post details about your tables so we have something to work with. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

In each of your queries you could determine row_number() based on the sort order currently used for TOP n - then you do a CASE based on the row_number

```
CASE WHEN row_number() OVER(...) <= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS sorter
```

Remove the TOP n in each case.

After you have done your union of 3 tables, take the TOP 12 from the UNION as a subquery, and order it by sorter ASC, NEWID().  That way you are guaranteed to have any 4 of the tables where they exist, and randoms from other tables to make up the numbers

e.g.

SELECT TOP 12 DQ.* FROM ('{your query}') DQ ORDER DQ.sorter ASC,newid()